# scope.$watch not working in bootstrap angularjs tabset

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this issue while trying to use angularjs $scope.$watch on an element within tab  the bootstrap ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js version whereby it's not working but if the elements is placed outside the tabset, it works fine and perfectly.

Anyone with the what's wrong should please quickly give response.

Comment: Could you add a plnkr please

Comment: i have been able to fix it. i thing it's an issue of child scope similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419605/angularjs-ui-tabset-scope-not-updating. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an another post with the solution for this: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1553

resume: put the variable in another one, example

models.variable

Its stupid but works