# Angular UI bootstrap tabs - Can't change tabs with a button inside a tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I'm trying to change my active tab with a button inside the tab directive `uib-tabset`, but the button is only working OUTSIDE this directive.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 0">Select first tab - exterior button</button>

<div class="tabs-container">
    <uib-tabset active="active">
        <uib-tab index="0" heading="tab one">
            tab one
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="1" heading="tab two">
            tab two
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 0">Select first tab - internal button</button>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="2" heading="tab three">
            tab three
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-click` within *uib-tab* directive in your case is trying to write to outer scope primitive variable, but creates local variable with the same name (*active*) on the local scope, thus breaking connection to outer scope. The easiest way is to add $parent.$parent to your inner click:

```
ng-click="$parent.$parent.active = 0"
```

which will reach correct outer scope (*outer scope -> uib-tabset -> uib-tab*) and then modify its variable,

another better solution is to use objects and modify its property (like *model.active*) when interacting between parent - child scopes:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-default btn-sm" 
        ng-click="model.active = 0">
  Select first tab - exterior button
</button>

<div class="tabs-container">
  <uib-tabset active="model.active">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="tab one">
        tab one
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="tab two">
        tab two
        <button type="button" 
                class="btn btn-default btn-sm" 
                ng-click="model.active = 0">
          Select first tab - internal button
        </button>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="tab three">
        tab three
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a function on controller: setCurrentTab(...). It will assert the correct place to set the value. Use like ng-click="setCurrentTab(0)"

Answer (score 1):

Reasonably sure there is some miscommunication between the two scopes on the page (`uib-tabset` is likely creating it's own scope that doesn't track your scopes `active` variable as well as we might like).

Check out this [**working plunker**](https://embed.plnkr.co/p6u9cGlTIUwz3JJy6N4L/) - you'll note it uses `ctrl as` syntax to more explicitly define which scopes variable to set with `ng-click`.

Here is a question regarding 2-way-binding issues within the `uib-tabset` scope **[found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560582/value-is-not-binding-with-scopes-variable-if-used-inside-uib-tabset)** that is the likely cause of the issue. I would suggest using `ctrl as` or you could bind to a $scope function to set `$scope.active` instead of binding to the `active` variable itself.