# When I change the view ($state.go(view)) I need to change tab

Tags: angularjs, directive, uitabview

I have a problem with a custom directive that I wrote to simulate a tab view in angular. 
This directive has only a method to redirect from a state to another.

This directive works fine.

The template of the directive is a `div` with a `uib-tabset` and some tabs that contain the views to  show them.

This works fine.

Now I need this feature: from a view in a tab, I need to change view with a `state.go(view)` and I  must also  go to the tab which contains that view.

I tried different solutions that I found here or in other forums, but probably my requested feature is different from others.

Thank you.

Comment: show us what you have done

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with the answer in this link.

Sorry for my repost.

[Angular UI bootstrap tabs - Can't change tabs with a button inside a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860391/angular-ui-bootstrap-tabs-cant-change-tabs-with-a-button-inside-a-tab)