# angular-ui-tabset: change active tab content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-tabset

I'm using `ui-tab` in my `angular` application. I have 2 tabs (tab1 and tab2) and I want to set tab1 as the active one programmatically when a button in the tab2.

This is my html code:

```
      <uib-tabset active="active"  justified="true">
        <uib-tab id="tab1" index="0" heading="Tab 1" ng-click="active= 0">
    <!-- content1 -->
        </uib-tab>
     <uib-tab id="tab2" index="1" heading="Tab 2" ng-click="active= 1">
    <!-- content2 -->
<button ng-click="goToTab1()"> Go to tab 1</button>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```

And this is the `goToTab1()` implementation:

```
$scope.goToTab1 = function() {
            angular.element(document.querySelector("#tab1")).removeClass("active");
            angular.element(document.querySelector("#tab2")).addClass("active");
}
```

My problem:

When I click the button (in the tab2) the tab1 is selected but the displayed content still the tab2 content. Also when after that I click on the tab2, nothing happened until I click on the tab1 one more then if I click on the tab2 it works.

**Edit**

I have already tried the solution in that [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860391/angular-ui-bootstrap-tabs-cant-change-tabs-with-a-button-inside-a-tab), but I'm getting the same problem.
Also when I change the active value directly in the `ng-click`, it has no effect at all

```
<button ng-click="active = 0"> Go to tab 1</button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860391/angular-ui-bootstrap-tabs-cant-change-tabs-with-a-button-inside-a-tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular UI bootstrap tabs - Can't change tabs with a button inside a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860391/angular-ui-bootstrap-tabs-cant-change-tabs-with-a-button-inside-a-tab)

Comment: @svarog I tried the answer in the issue that you gave me but it doesn't work

Comment: ok, then edit your question and add your second attempt, this way your question won't duplicate the other one and won't eventually close

Comment: @svarog check my edit please

Answer (score 0):

```
<uib-tabset active="current"  justified="true">
  <uib-tab id="tab1" index="0" heading="Tab 1" ng-click="current = 0">
    <!-- content1 -->
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab id="tab2" index="1" heading="Tab 2" ng-click="current = 1">
    <!-- content2 -->
    <button ng-click="goToTab1()"> Go to tab 1</button>
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

```
$scope.goToTab1 = function() {
  $scope.current = 0;
};
```

Comment: Maybe you're not using the controller where you've defined the function in the specific tabset snippet.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860391/angular-ui-bootstrap-tabs-cant-change-tabs-with-a-button-inside-a-tab), you should refactor

```
<button ng-click="active = 0"> Go to tab 1</button>
```

To

```
<button ng-click="$parent.$parent.active = 0"> Go to tab 1</button>
```

I think a better apprache would be to used views/directives with their own scopes and hide/show them according to `active`